# How to find ALL child elements with same class via js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to find all elements with specific class.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="pb-30 faq" id="faq-1">
 <div class="flex flex-row">
  <div class="w-20">
    <div class="hw-24 lol close" id="test">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="close-dialog lol" id="test-2">
 <div class="flex flex-col">
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I want to find elements with class `lol`.

I can find first child, but not the other once. Here is my simple js code:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".faq").forEach(x => x.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    faqToggle(this.id)
}))

function faqToggle(id) {
    const clickedFaq = document.querySelectorAll(`div#${id} > div.lol`)
    console.log(clickedFaq)
}
```

Thank you for help

Comment: jQuery .........

Comment: @GetSet this is not jQuery though? or are you suggesting he used jQuery? if that's the case then i wholeheartedly disagree

Comment: I prefer pure JS.

Comment: Then you prefer the reinvention too

Comment: @GetSet You're not helping. Pretty much any selector supported by jQuery is supported as a CSS selector in pure JavaScript.

Comment: Point is, i dont mean to be smug. But jQuery does solve these sorts of problems in dev work

Comment: Your element with the class `faq` only _has_ one child with the class `lol` here.

Comment: @GetSet Recommending people to use jQuery in 2020 is not in keeping with the times.

Comment: Comes with some appreciation of times past @RobbyCornelissen. Besides the library has the cross browser solution for OP. But let us copy it and give no credit in 2020

Comment: @GetSet The cross-browser solution for OP is available in vanilla JavaScript (as demonstrated by the answer below). Stop muddying the waters.

Comment: Then my "comment" was not a farce @RobbyCornelissen. Had you read, i said he/she could read the jQuery open source.

Comment: @GetSet Let this be my last comment: in this case, the selector that would have to be used in jQuery is exactly the same as the standard CSS selector to be used in vanilla JS. The fix for this problem in jQuery would be exactly the same as in standard JS. Reading the jQuery source code does no one any good.

Comment: I prefer pure JS, just because i am weak with jQuery :-) Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The greater than sign (`>`) selector in CSS is used to select the element with a specific parent. It is called as element > element selector. It is also known as the child combinator selector which means that it selects only those elements which are direct children of a parent. It looks only one level down the markup structure and not further deep down. Elements which are not the direct child of the specified parent is not selected.

Instead you should use a `white space` to match all descendants of an element

```js
const clickedFaq = document.querySelectorAll(`div#faq-1 div.lol`);
console.log(clickedFaq)
```

```html
<div class="pb-30 faq" id="faq-1">
  <div class="flex flex-row">
    <div class="w-20">
      <div class="hw-24 lol close" id="test">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="close-dialog lol" id="test-2">
    <div class="flex flex-col">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) instead of the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

That means in the selector replace `>` with a whitespace  .

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".faq .lol"));
```

```html
 <div class="pb-30 faq" id="faq-1">
   <div class="flex flex-row">
     <div class="w-20">
       <div class="hw-24 lol close" id="test">
         test
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="close-dialog lol" id="test-2">
     test
     <div class="flex flex-col">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```